# How do I get the value of the disabled attribute with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html

*I couldn't find this specific wording anywhere and so the solution was hard to find.*

I have an element and I want to find out if it is disabled or not in my javascript. How do I get the value of the disabled attribute of the element?

Comment: simple - `element.getAttribute('disabled');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When I tried searching for this specific wording I found a lot of related questions on stackoverflow, but not this one. I figured it out from other posts and what I already know, but since I did not find this specific question clearly asked in stackoverflow, I hope this helps someone less experienced find the answer.*

You should be looking for the value of the `disabled` *property* of the HTML element instead of the *attribute*.

`disabled` is both an attribute and a property, but only the property is really useful. You get it in your js like this:

```js
let myElement = document.document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
let is_disabled = myElement.disabled;
// true or false
```

The [MDN page on `disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) is no help. It only talks about `disabled` as an attribute. Maybe there is another page in the MDN that I have not found yet that explains it better.

An attribute has to do with HTML. In the code below, `class` is an attribute:

```html
<input class="the-best"/>
```

It has a value right there in the HTML. You get the value of an attribute with `.getAttribute()`:

```js
let classNames = myElement.getAttribute('class');
// "the-best"
```

A property has to do with javascript. In javascript, when you get an element you get an object with a bunch of properties and methods. For example, you can get the [inner height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) of the element like this:

```js
let inner_height = myElement.clientHeight;
// Some number
```

In HTML, `disabled` looks like this:

```html
<input disabled/>
```

You can see `disabled` in the HTML, but it does not have a value. If it does have any value, then it **is** disabled, even if that value is `"false"`. You can do `myElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'false')` and you'll get `<input disabled="false">` which **still disables the element**. Basically, if `disabled` is in the HTML **in any way** the element is disabled. If it is not in the HTML then the element is NOT disabled. `.getAttribute()` will work like this:

```js
// <input disabled/>
let is_disabled = myElement.getAttribute('disabled');
// "" - an empty string
```

```js
// <input/>
let is_disabled = myElement.getAttribute('disabled');
// null
```

You can probably still use `.getAttribute()` if you want since you can check for a `string` or `null`, but people sometimes do weird things with their HTML and the "values" of these kinds of attributes (like what I described above).